VS Code gives error stating installed libraries are missing
VSCode problems image
Previously been smoothly using VSCode and was able to run the code with no issue but this error has randomly been popping up when i use any python library.
I tried to run the code in a separate file and it somehow worked there but after booting up VSCode the next day it shown the error again. I would be very grateful if u guys can help me resolve the issue. Thank you for ur time.

the linter (in this case pylance) is expecting to see the modules mentioned, but cannot find them. So, are they installed correctly ?

Yes they were installed correctly and had been working fine b4 I tried deleting and reinstalling as well

Hello, do you have multiple python environments? This may be the reason for the location where the module is installed. You can go to the command panel by Ctrl+Shift+P and type select interpreter to select the interpreter with the module installed. In addition, you may want to check that the settings of the Pylance plugin are aware of the python environment and module paths.
